# Dart - type 'List<int>' is not a subtype of type 'List<List<int>>' of 'function result'

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to generate an 8x8 grid with ids ranging from 0-63.

Here's the data for my board:

```
final List<List<int>> ids = [
  List.generate(8, (i) => i), // 0 - 7
  List.generate(8, (i) => i + 1 + 7), // 8 - 15
  List.generate(8, (i) => i + 2 + 14), // 16 - 23
  List.generate(8, (i) => i + 3 + 21 ), // 24 - 31
  List.generate(8, (i) => i + 4 + 28), // 32 - 39
  List.generate(8, (i) => i + 5 + 35), // 40 - 47
  List.generate(8, (i) => i + 6 + 42), // 48 - 55
  List.generate(8, (i) => i + 7 + 49) // 56 - 63
];
```

And here's the function that iterates the data to create the board:

```
List<Row> buildBoard() {

  return ids.map((row) {

    return Row(
      children: row.map((id) {

        return Expanded(
          child: () {
            /* ... omitted for readability ... */
          }()
        );
      }).toList()
    );
  }).toList();
}
```

I don't get any lint errors but when I run the code here:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(
    children: buildBoard()
  );
}
```

I get the following error:

```
type 'List<int>' is not a subtype of type 'List<List<int>>' of 'function result'
```

I can't figure out why this is happening, tried looking at other answers but without success.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Seriously, try restarting your IDE. It should work.

Comment: @Blasanka Mmmh, wasn't the IDE's fault but a hot restart rather than a reload was required...

Comment: Yeah, when you do some hard stuff like adding global variables, you have to hot reatart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unable to reproduce the issue. Working good for me

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: FirstPage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FirstPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<List<int>> ids = [
    List.generate(8, (i) => i), // 0 - 7
    List.generate(8, (i) => i + 1 + 7), // 8 - 15
    List.generate(8, (i) => i + 2 + 14), // 16 - 23
    List.generate(8, (i) => i + 3 + 21), // 24 - 31
    List.generate(8, (i) => i + 4 + 28), // 32 - 39
    List.generate(8, (i) => i + 5 + 35), // 40 - 47
    List.generate(8, (i) => i + 6 + 42), // 48 - 55
    List.generate(8, (i) => i + 7 + 49) // 56 - 63
  ];

  List<Row> buildBoard() {
    return ids.map((row) {
      return Row(
          children: row.map((id) {
        return Expanded(
          child: Material(
            child: Text("id_$id"),
          ),
        );
      }).toList());
    }).toList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
        children: buildBoard()
    );
  }
}
```